# MySQL database hostname

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, webserver, hostname

I have created a MySQL database and a table via cPanel on a web server of mine. My question is this: How can I access this Database and Table from a Visual Basic.net application?

What do I use as the host address? The http address to the web server is http://www.canninginc.co.nz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to connect to MySQL from a remote location (for example from your computer), please use these instructions:

1. Use the IP address of your hosting account as your MySQL hostname.
   Your IP address can by found on the left hand column when you login
   to cPanel.
2. Please add your computer IP address to the cPanel -> Remote MySQL section. You can check the computer IP address at http://www.tracemyip.org/
3. Use either the MYSQL username / password that was created in cPanel -> MYSQL section, or your cPanel login details to connect to the database

Comment: How about if I am releasing the application to the public? I cannot add all the users IP addresses to cPanel. Is this possible?

Comment: You may use % as a wildcard. For instance, to allow access from all IP addresses beginning with 192.68.0, you can enter 192.68.0.%.

Comment: How about allowing all IP addresses? Do I just use a % at the start?

Comment: simply enter %. This will allow any IP to remotely connect to your databases.

Comment: I cannot see the IP address of the hosting account for your 1. Is it just the Main Domain address?